# Who can technically view saved drafts for questions and answers

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, drafts

As the post [When I go to "Ask Question" here at superuser, how do I get an empty form? My previous question keeps showing up.](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1810/when-i-go-to-ask-question-here-at-superuser-how-do-i-get-an-empty-form-my-pr/1812#1812) states. . .

> Stack Exchange sites will save a question or answer you're composing
>   after a while. You'll see a "draft saved" message when this happens.
>   (If you switch to another browser, log in, and go to the same page
>   you'll see the stuff you entered will re-appear, confirming it's
>   actually saved on the server.)

Is this "saved draft" message or question content accessible to anyone else such as everyone, mods only, the server admins only, etc? I wonder if any of these could be a "yes but it depends" for various scenarios and such or not ever at all just the OP of the Q or A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the OP. I can't view those drafts - and while devs might be able to, in theory, I'm doubtful it's a function that would be used.

Comment: Quick clarification follow up, so when you go to close a question that has no answers on it deleted or not yet submitted, you do not see anything that indicates someone is writing up an answer that is in a saved draft state or anything like that either, correct? As a mod, you have no indicator that a question you are about to close has someone writing up an answer on it that has yet to be submitted whether or not auto save draft kicked in or not yet?

Comment: Nope. We literally see the same thing you do. Just with a weightier hammer